# Was Java originally designed for a toaster?

Tags: programming-languages, java

I've heard this tossed around few times, but never really a source. The wiki page says it was designed for home appliances, but never really references a toaster. Anyone have a source?

Comment: I dunno... I don't think toasters would need a JVM. If there's a NullPointerException, would I at least get my toast back?

Comment: @Frustrated Yes, I believe the `popup();` is in a `finally` block.

Comment: @Renesis: That made my Friday awesome!

Comment: @Renesis - good one :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Originally it was designed (by Sun's James Gosling) for embedded systems, in particular mobile devices such as e.g. cell phones. See e.g. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview/javahistory-index-198355.html

Comment: So it was invented for a cable remote control.  +1 for the *real* answer. :)

Comment: The thing they were thinking long and hard about was "how can we execute arbitrary downloaded code, and still be in control".

Answer (score 4):

No, but I have to admit, sometimes it makes me feel like it was.

Embedded systems was one of the target markets though, there were even some attempts at developing processors that would run native Java bytecode.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jazelle (for ARM processors)

Comment: @mmyers Yeah, I remember that. There was something similar planned for Transmeta Crusoes too. It never quite caught on though.

Comment: www.ajile.com make a CPU running a JRE in embedded hardware. They are great for embedded, as the java code is very reliable. Power consumption is less than a watt, at 100% CPU, down to nanowatts when asleep.

Comment: @mmyers http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAJC **"...processor was targeted at running Java programs..."**

Answer (score 1):

My pen runs java. [LiveScribe](http://www.livescribe.com/en-gb/). I think I first started to see Java being used around 1996 or 1997? All my memories of it at that time were that it was big on the write once run anywhere deal, running on any device, but particularly in a browser as applets. Then I recall Microsoft came in with a competing JVM that "extended" Java to run specific Windows functionality. 
Not conclusive, but hopefully interesting.